# Strange behavior with c++ recursive templates when c++11 is enabled

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, recursion, clang++

I'm trying to understand some recursive C++ template code I've been handed, and I'm hitting some strange behavior.  For some reason, the compiler seems able to add two values at compile-time but doing a left-shift has to be left for run-time.  And even then, the problem only occurs if I try to build with c++11 enabled.

The code (which I've boiled down and you will see later) defines two pairs of templates - one pair named `shft` and `shft_aux` and one pair named `add` and `add_aux` that generate themselves recursively.  BTW, the `add` template is not supposed to be useful, its sole purpose is to demonstrate the problem, not to generate an actual `min` value.

If I compile this code with no command-line parameters, it compiles just fine.  But if I specify `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`, the static_assert on add_aux is still fine but the static_assert on shft_aux now generates a compile-time error saying `static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression`.

Why is left-shift treated differently from addition?

Thanks,
Chris

p.s. I'm using clang++ version `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`

```
#include <climits>

template <unsigned size> struct shft; // forward

template <unsigned size>
struct shft_aux
{
    static const int min = shft<size>::min;
};

template <unsigned size>
struct shft
{
    typedef shft_aux<size - 1> prev;
    static const int min = prev::min << CHAR_BIT;
};

// Base specialization of shft, puts an end to the recursion.
template <>
struct shft<1>
{
    static const int min = SCHAR_MIN;
};


// -----

template <unsigned size> struct add; // forward

template <unsigned size>
struct add_aux
{
    static const int min = add<size>::min;
};

template <unsigned size>
struct add
{
    typedef add_aux<size - 1> prev;
    static const int min = prev::min + CHAR_BIT;
};

// Base specialization of add, puts an end to the recursion.
template <>
struct add<1>
{
    static const int min = SCHAR_MIN;
};


// -----

int main()
{
    static_assert(shft_aux<sizeof(int)>::min < 0, "min is not negative");
    static_assert(add_aux<sizeof(int)>::min < 0, "min is not negative");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Frankly, I don't quite understand what you want to do with that.. maybe there's a *solution* to your problem and not just some language-lawyer remark about what the Standard allows.

Comment: It's like the old joke ... "Doctor, it hurts when I do this" ... "So don't do that!"  Now that I fully understand the issue, and have the backing of the Standard, I feel confident in proposing a different way of solving the problem that doesn't require left-shifting of negative numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++11 Standard, [expr.shift]/2

> The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If `E1` has an unsigned type, [...]. Otherwise, if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and *E1*2<sup>E2</sup>* is representable
>   in the result type, then that is the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

[emphasis mine]

This is affected slightly by [DR1457](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1457) which makes shifting *into the "sign-bit"* defined behaviour:

> Otherwise, if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and *E1*2<sup>E2</sup>* is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type [...].

Anyway, in the OP, `E1` is negative, so that's still Undefined Behaviour. As such, it is not allowed inside *constant expressions*:

> [expr.const]/2
>   A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless it involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression [...]
>
> - [...]
> - a result that is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type;

That point has changed ([DR1313](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1313)); in n3485 it says:

> - an operation that would have undefined behavior  [ *Note:* including, for example, signed integer over-
>     flow (Clause 5), certain pointer arithmetic (5.7), division by zero (5.6), or certain shift operations (5.8)
>     *— end note* ];

---

[class.static.data]/3

> If a non-volatile `const static` data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which **every *initializer-clause* that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression**

---

Conclusion: shifting `SCHAR_MIN` is not a constant expression, so you can't do that in the in-class initializer of a static data member.

Hint: always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Using no parameters IMO is a bad idea for g++ and compatible compilers. g++/clang++ per default use the `gnu99` mode ([see clang doc](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#differences-between-various-standard-modes)), which is an extension to C++98 AFAIK. Also, you'll miss many important warnings.

Comment: Somehow I get the impression quoting the Standard itself is not very useful. Maybe I should stick to my motto "n3485 is the best draft for C++11".

Comment: I'm very grateful that you quoted the Standard!  Did you get some negative feedback for doing so?

Comment: @BettyCrokker I used to only quote from n3485; mixing both n3485 and the International Standard could be confusing. The differences typically only matter for language-lawyers, since most compiler maintainers eventually implement the proposed resolutions of defects. Also, the differences don't really matter for your question, so they might be just noise here.

Comment: @dyp I remembered this comment you made on `N3485` and I was wondering if you have anything to add to [this comment thread on N3485](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047109/classes-with-both-template-and-non-template-conversion-operators-in-the-conditio#comment38992224_25047109).