# implicit conversion from class to enumeration type in switch conditional

Tags: c++, c++11, switch-statement, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

g++ 4.9.0 accepts the following code:

```
enum E { foo };

struct C {
  operator E() const { return foo; }
  operator E() { return foo; }
};

int main() {
  C c;
  switch (c) {
    case foo: break;
  }
}
```

But clang 3.4.1 rejects it with the following diagnostic:

```
12 : error: multiple conversions from switch condition type 'C' to an integral or enumeration type
switch (c)
^ ~
5 : note: conversion to enumeration type 'E'
operator E() const { return foo; }
^
6 : note: conversion to enumeration type 'E'
operator E() { return foo; }
^
```

Which one is correct? Is it a clang bug, g++ bug, libstdc++ bug, standard defect, or other? Did I do something stupid?

In the code which triggered this question, `C` is `std::atomic<E>`, and `std::atomic<T>::operator T` is overloaded on the cv-qualifiers `const` and `const volatile`.

Both compilers accept `E e = c;`, so it seems to be something peculiar to the `switch` statement.

Comment: Related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25047109/1708801)

Comment: Note that clang 3.4.1 accepts it when `-std=c++1y`

Comment: As dyp had noted earlier(*the comment is now gone*) the crux of the problem lies whether contextual implicit conversions are part of C++11 which is why this is related to [Classes with both template and non-template conversion operators in the condition of switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047109/classes-with-both-template-and-non-template-conversion-operators-in-the-conditio/25048219#25048219) which I mentioned as being related, even though the specific issue is different.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a difference between C++11 and C++14; clang correctly accepts it in C++14 mode (`-std=c++1y`) and rejects it in C++11 mode (`-std=c++11`), while gcc is incorrect to accept it in C++11 mode.

The behavior of `switch` statements was changed by paper [n3323](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3323.pdf), which landed after the C++11 standard was finalized.

**[stmt.switch]**, in C++11:

> 2 - The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or of a class type for which **a single non-explicit conversion function** to integral or enumeration type exists (12.3). [...]

In n3936 (wording per n3323):

> 2 - The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or class type. If of class type, the condition is **contextually implicitly converted** (Clause 4) to an integral or enumeration type.

Contextual implicit conversion is a variant of implicit conversion (i.e. the declaration `T t = e` is required to be well-formed); for contextual implicit conversion to be well-formed the class type `E` is allowed to have multiple conversion functions, but all those valid in the context must have the same return type modulo *cv* and reference qualification: **[conv]**

> 5 - [...] `E` is searched for conversion functions whose return type is *cv* `T` or
>   reference to *cv* `T` such that `T` is allowed by the context. There shall be exactly one such `T`.

In a `switch` statement, contextual implicit conversion is *to an integral or enumeration type*, so `C` must have at least one non-`explicit` conversion function to *cv* integral or enumeration type or reference to *cv* integral or enumeration type, and *all* its conversion functions to *cv* integral or enumeration type or reference to *cv* integral or enumeration type must have that same underlying type.

A pretty nice workaround (as mentioned in n3323) is to use unary plus to coerce the argument of the `switch` statement to arithmetic type:

```
  switch (+c) {
    // ...
```

Comment: So does it fail in C++11 mode because there's more than one conversion?

Comment: @0x499602D2 yes, that's right; in C++14 it is OK because although there are two conversions they are to the same *type*, modulo *cv* and reference.

Answer (score 5):

I believe `clang` is correct here, depending on which version of the standard is being used. I usually use [N3485](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) as a C++11 after fixes reference but it could be argued that the change that I noted in [Classes with both template and non-template conversion operators in the condition of switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25048219/1708801) are an addition and thus are actually part of C++1y.

So going with the contention that *contextually implicit conversions* is a addition then `clang` is correct for the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf). Due to section `6.4.2` *The switch statement* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or of a
>   class type for which a single non-explicit conversion function to
>   integral or enumeration type exists (12.3).[...]

In C++1y then this should be acceptable code and running this in C++1y mode in `clang` seems to confirm this is indeed the case (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6898ae803273d1f)*).

We can see from the [draft C++1y standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) section `6.4.2` *The switch statement* that this involves a *contextually implicit conversion*. Paragraph *2* says:

> The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or class
>   type. If of class type, the condition is **contextually implicitly
>   converted (Clause 4)** to an integral or enumeration type.

We can see the section we need to use is `4` *Standard conversions* and paragraph *5* covers these cases, it says:

> Certain language constructs require conversion to a value having one
>   of a specified set of types appropriate to the construct. An
>   expression e of class type E appearing in such a context is said to be
>   **contextually implicitly converted** to a specified type T and is
>   well-formed if and only if e can be implicitly converted to a type T
>   that is determined as follows: E is searched for conversion functions
>   whose return type is cv T or reference to cv T such that T is allowed
>   by the context. There shall be exactly one such T.