# Using an atomic enum class in C++11 switch statement

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, stdatomic

Not sure this is possible, but if so, how do you use an atomic enum class for a switch statement in C++11? For example,

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

enum class A {RED, FRUIT, APPLE};

int main(){
    std::atomic<A> myAtomicEnum;
    myAtomicEnum = A::RED;
    switch (myAtomicEnum){
        case A::RED:
            std::cout << "A::RED \n";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

gives a compiler error

```
error: multiple conversions from switch condition type
      'std::atomic<A>' to an integral or enumeration type
    switch (myAtomicEnum){
```

A different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143860/implicit-conversion-from-class-to-enumeration-type-in-switch-conditional) using an enum class (not atomic) forced a conversion to arithmetic type using a unary +, but you can't pass an `std::atomic<A>` to the unary +. I don't receive any errors using a non-atomic enum class and not using a unary +, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class A {RED, FRUIT, APPLE};

int main(){
    A myEnum = A::RED;
    switch (myEnum){
        case A::RED:
            std::cout << "A::RED \n";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs `A::RED` as expected.

The context of the problem is that I have a class with a member that may be read/written to by multiple threads and a switch statement using that member. I have a workaround using mutex-es so that I have well-defined behavior but would like to use `atomic` if possible.

Comment: Does not seem wrong to me. Perhaps specify platform, compiler and command line and full error message verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ 11, you may explicitly cast atomic type variable to enum type, this will call `std::atomic<T>::operator T()` casting operator of the object:

```
switch ((A)myAtomicEnum){
    case A::RED:
        ...
```

Btw, starting from C++ 14 this explicit cast is not needed, and cast to switch type will be done implicitly ([cppreference.com, Implicit conversions page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion))

Comment: Thank you! Accepted as the answer, I did not realize I could do this. For the sake of searching for casts, I am partial to `switch(static_cast<A>(myAtomicEnum))` even though it is more verbose.

Comment: @MikeM: I'd have done `myAtomicEnum.load()` to get a `T` from `atomic<T>`.  https://godbolt.org/z/37T5hfrjM .  (I can't reproduce the error on Godbolt even with old gcc `-std=c++11`; their `<atomic>` header is new enough I guess?)

Comment: Turned out gcc with `-std=c++11` makes implicit cast, but clang with `-std=c++11` and no explicit cast shows compilation error